# USB ports on expansion card are not working

Tags: linux, usb, bios

A few days ago I installed a new cpu fan and some extra ram-memory.

All went fine, however when connecting a usb device to my pci-expansion card it does not work at all.

The first error code I'm tracked down is -110 which appeared to be a timeout. Several people appeared to solve this by plugging everything off and reconnecting, but not for me (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/usb-error-110-a-4175600294/)

The second error I could find in my dmesg is `ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)`. This appears to be kernel non-issue that needs to be solved with a bios update. Problem with applying this fix: there is no bios update. (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/acpi-error-%5Bdssp%5D-namespace-lookup-failure-ae_not_found-on-slackware-14-64-bit-4175448907/)

I tried looking for other issues with the expansion card and it seems that the chipset on it has some issues (https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1332722 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1353050) but none of them seems to be recent.

I also tried using different usb and pci device, also formatting my pc and taking out GPU but it all does not seems to help either. Can someone please advice?

```
jeroen@apple-juice-test:~$ dmesg | grep "xhci\|usb\|ACPI"
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000083495000-0x0000000083495fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008a32a000-0x000000008a9cffff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x8a62a000  ACPI=0x8a62a000  SMBIOS=0x8b2cc000  MPS=0xfca20  ESRT=0x88271658 
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x000000008A62A000 000024 (v02 ALASKA)
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x000000008A62A0A0 0000C4 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x000000008A650E50 000114 (v06 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000008A62A200 026C4F (v02 ALASKA A M I    01072009 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x000000008A9CFC40 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000008A650F68 0000BC (v03 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FPDT 0x000000008A651028 000044 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000008A651070 00003C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A6510B0 0003BC (v01 SataRe SataTabl 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FIDT 0x000000008A651470 00009C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A651510 003159 (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A654670 00255F (v02 PegSsd PegSsdt  00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x000000008A656BD0 000038 (v01 INTEL  SKL      00000001 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A656C08 000DE5 (v02 INTEL  Ther_Rvp 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A6579F0 000A29 (v02 INTEL  xh_rvp08 00000000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000008A658420 000042 (v01 INTEL  EDK2     00000002      01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A658468 000EDE (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LPIT 0x000000008A659348 000094 (v01 INTEL  SKL      00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: WSMT 0x000000008A6593E0 000028 (v01 INTEL  SKL      00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A659408 00029F (v02 INTEL  sensrhub 00000000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008A6596A8 003002 (v02 INTEL  PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DBGP 0x000000008A65C6B0 000034 (v01 INTEL           00000002 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DBG2 0x000000008A65C6E8 000054 (v00 INTEL           00000002 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BGRT 0x000000008A65C740 000038 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x1808
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x05] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x06] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x07] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x08] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: Core revision 20170831
[    0.000000] ACPI: 9 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.057059] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x83495000-0x83495fff] (4096 bytes)
[    0.057059] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x8a32a000-0x8a9cffff] (6971392 bytes)
[    0.057100] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.057100] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.057100] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.060041] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.060041] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.060042] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.060042] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.060043] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.060043] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.060044] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.060937] ACPI: Executed 36 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.073312] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.076769] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.076774] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E7531800 000717 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.076993] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.077066] ACPI: \_PR_.CPU0: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.078416] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.078419] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E7604800 0003FF (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.078620] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.078765] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.078768] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E75FC800 000115 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.078941] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.079015] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.079018] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E75FF800 0001A4 (v02 PmRef  HwpLvt   00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.079186] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.079572] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.079576] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E7533000 00065C (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.080026] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.080165] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.080168] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E75FE200 000197 (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.080369] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.080510] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.080513] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9779E75FCC00 00018A (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.080714] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.084368] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.084400] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.084400] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.084430] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.085459] ACPI: Enabled 6 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    0.087746] ACPI: Power Resource [PG00] (on)
[    0.088153] ACPI: Power Resource [PG01] (on)
[    0.088546] ACPI: Power Resource [PG02] (on)
[    0.091367] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.091684] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.092009] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.092327] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.092643] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.092956] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.093272] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.093594] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.093908] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.094221] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.094536] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.094850] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.095168] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.095483] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.095798] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.096115] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.096430] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.097657] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.097972] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.098286] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
[    0.110510] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
[    0.110593] ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
[    0.110672] ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
[    0.110751] ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
[    0.110831] ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
[    0.111995] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-fe])
[    0.120835] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.120887] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.120937] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.120989] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.121040] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.121090] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.121141] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.121193] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.121824] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.121824] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.121824] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.121824] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.142831] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.179542] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.179847] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.180356] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0400 (active)
[    0.180711] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
[    0.180830] system 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.180909] system 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.180921] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.180954] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT3f0d PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.181179] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.181218] system 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.181487] system 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.182571] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.183375] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
[    0.848568] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    0.848592] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.848658] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.968252] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[    0.968393] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (30 C)
[    1.014668] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.014671] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.015753] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000001109810
[    1.015757] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.015868] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.015869] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.015870] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.015871] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.015871] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.017161] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.017163] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.017164] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0  SuperSpeed
[    1.017187] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.017188] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.017188] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.017189] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.017190] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.017842] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.018214] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.018217] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.077104] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: hcc params 0x0200eec1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000000010
[    1.077267] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.077268] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.077268] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.077269] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.077270] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
[    1.077424] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.077425] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.077427] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.077450] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.077459] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.077460] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.077460] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.077461] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.077462] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
[    1.077659] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.077664] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    1.077775] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000000000090
[    1.077870] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.077870] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.077871] usb usb5: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.077872] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.077872] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:03:00.0
[    1.078016] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.078018] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    1.078019] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0  SuperSpeed
[    1.078033] usb usb6: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.078043] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.078044] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.078045] usb usb6: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.078045] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.078046] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:03:00.0
[    1.356071] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.412064] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.505384] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b
[    1.505385] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.636051] usb 1-11: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.736460] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    1.792362] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0941
[    1.792363] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.792364] usb 1-11: Product: HP X500 USB Optical Mouse
[    1.792365] usb 1-11: Manufacturer: PixArt
[    1.920005] usb 1-12: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.035116] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.035124] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.035428] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.035433] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.035480] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.035487] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.035906] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.035910] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.036394] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.036402] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT2._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.036560] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.036567] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.036664] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.036668] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT3._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.037254] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[    2.037263] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT2._GTF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    2.069060] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c336
[    2.069061] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.069061] usb 1-12: Product: Gaming Keyboard G213
[    2.069062] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.069062] usb 1-12: SerialNumber: 117F36563633
[    2.075559] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.075559] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.076559] input: PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/0003:03F0:0941.0001/input/input4
[    2.076609] hid-generic 0003:03F0:0941.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-11/input0
[    2.076675] input: Logitech Gaming Keyboard G213 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/0003:046D:C336.0002/input/input5
[    2.136212] hid-generic 0003:046D:C336.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Gaming Keyboard G213] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input0
[    2.136328] input: Logitech Gaming Keyboard G213 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.1/0003:046D:C336.0003/input/input6
[    2.196478] hid-generic 0003:046D:C336.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Gaming Keyboard G213] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input1
[    6.752485] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   22.368468] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   22.604129] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   27.744471] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   43.360476] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   43.468145] usb usb5-port1: attempt power cycle
[   44.120129] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   54.376132] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
[   54.392137] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
[   54.392138] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[   54.392140] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[   54.392151] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   54.808126] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 4, error -108
[   54.808150] usb usb5-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
[   63.016019] parport_pc 00:01: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   64.292379] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
```

Comment: Have you tried a different USB device?   Do you get the same problem with different devices?  Have you tried a different pci-expansion card?

Comment: Yes, I tried using another usb device and pci device. Also power issues can be excluded from possible causes as issue persists while gpu (GTX 960 requiring additional 8-pin header) was taken out of the pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue. Because I have seen a lot of people suffering the same issue here is my cause and my solution.

## The cause

(Note: this is based on assumptions from what I have seen and done. They are not necessarily facts or the true cause)

A few days before the issue started I accidently broke my cpu-fan. This required me to renew the cpu-fan. While I did this, I took advantage of that my pc was open to install a memory-upgrade. This memory-upgrade caused motherboard to initiate a bios-reset.

Because this is a common step when installing new/more memory, the pcie-expansion card, who was in the pcie-port before, during and after memory-upgrade, caused to initiate a bios-reset of its controller as well which rendered the pcie-card in a not configured state.

## The solution

(Note: the solution is specific for expansion cards based on the [VIA VL 805/806](https://www.via-labs.com/product_show.php?id=48) chipset)

### Short answer:

I solved the issue by upgrading the bios of the pcie expansion card

### Long answer:

First of all, you need a bare-metal windows machine. If you have one, you can use a windows partition. If you don't, you can download a windows based boot disk. Myself I used [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/). If you enable iommu in the bios you should be able to use a virtual machine as well, but I wouldn't recommend it personally as other and better options are available.

The second thing you'll need is a firmware upgrade for the chipset of your expansion card. Since mine was based on the VIA VL805 chipset I could use this one (https://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=startdown&id=3495&lang=en).

Next is to boot windows and install the firmware update using the tool found in the zip-folder you download (my downloaded file was exe, but is actually a zip. I think this was a wrong translation on the site's backend)

Since I try to be generic I'm not providing detailed instructions on updating the firmware update tool. If you situation is 100% the same, instructions can be found the zip folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just registered (so I cannot vote or comment) to let you know, that upgrading firmware on my generic VL805 card fixed issue where it was not visible after system reboot using MSI 790FX-GD70 motherboard. Thanks a lot!

Since posting the previous answer, a newer version of firmware became available: https://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=fileinfo&id=4411&lang=en